# Is it not possible to use variable for selector in `wrapper.find(selector)` in Enzyme.js?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, enzyme

I rendered the wrapper for component using `shallow`, then I have an object which keys correspond to classnames in HTML. But when I want to use a reusable function to find the proper html elements, I get an error. When I access them normally, for example wrapper.find('.time') the test is passed.

I see no comments about use of variables here: https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html

My code is:

```
    let wrapper;

beforeEach(() => {
  wrapper = shallow(<MarketHistoryTableEntry data={rowData}/>);
});

it('should render entry content', function () {
  const entryData = {
    '.time': "18:38:39 23/07/2021",
    '.key': 103,
    '.status': "AUTO"
  };

 for (let entry in entryData) {
    expect(wrapper.find(entry).text()).to.be.equal(entryData[entry]);
  }
```

The error that I get is:    `Error: Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the code is correct and it is perfectly valid to use variable as selector. The error came from the fact, that one of the classes I had in `entryData` was wrong because I wrote it like this `.time after start` instead of `.time-after-start`.